# SharePoint 2010 Sandboxed solutions performance

Tags: sandbox-solution, performance

Does code that is deployed through a Sandboxed solution perform just a well as code deployed through a Farm solution?

Does the overhead that comes with interprocess communication (since Sandboxed code runs in SPUserCodeV4.exe) have any effect on the performance of custom code?

Answer (score 4):

I asked that question at the SharePoint Conference and they said there shouldn't be any performance difference.  I agree with you though, I would think that unpackaging the wsp, opening a new process, and returning the result would means slower page loads on whatever is using that functionality.

Answer (score 4):

There should be almost no difference. In any case the extra time required for interprocess communication is very small compared with getting data from the database.

There are two main reasons to use a sandboxed solution:

- You plan to deploy it to the cloud (SharePoint Online Services)
- To improve managability and security

There are many situtations where the requirements of a system do not allow you to use a Sandboxed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on Developer Dashboard.

My experiment:
Page with farm web-part - Execution Time  38.95 ms
Page with empty sandboxed web-part - Execution Time  384.12 ms

This only one sandboxed web-part that do noting...

Comment: Correct, I have experienced a slow down too.  This is down to how sandboxing works - creating a copy of the page object, running the sandbox with that, then merging back to the parent page object.